# Asp.Net: Client side validation for mandatory field

Tags: asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a textbox control

```
 <div id="divFirstName" runat="server">
            <label>First Name:<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_FirstName" runat="server" TabIndex="1" CssClass="text" onkeypress="clearMessage()" ></asp:TextBox>
 </div>
```

I am applying required field validator for the above control,

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="reqFirstName" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txt_FirstName" Display="None" ErrorMessage="First Name is required." />
```

Now in a particular sequence I need to disable the validator applied for the text control. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Do you know jQuery? things like this are much easier handled with jQuery i.m.o.

Comment: still it doesn't solve the server side validation

Comment: @ Ivo: can u help me with sample code? I tried 
     `code`var myVal = document.getElementById('txt_FirstName');
          ValidatorEnable(myVal, false);`code` but in vain though

Comment: @jithin, you need to pass the validator control to the `ValidatorEnable` - for example, `ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('reqFirstName'), false);`

Comment: [jQuery Plugins/Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to disable the validator control. From server side, you can use [Enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.enabled.aspx) property. For example,

```
reqFirstName.Enabled = false;
```

In case, you want to disable the validator on client side w/o taking the post-back then you should use client side API for validators. For example,

```
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%=reqFirstName.ClientID%>'), false);
```

Note that even if you disable the validator on the client side, it would be still enable on the server and will trigger validation on the post-back. So you have to handle this situation on server side by probably disabling the validator early in the page life cycle.

For more information on client side API for validators, see this: http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/How-to-control-ASP-NET-Validator-Controls-Client-Side-validation-from-JavaScript.aspx